# How to get ID of button I'm clicking

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Long story short: I'm trying to create something like a social media feed of posts fetched from a database. What I'm having problems with is the liking system. I'm fetching data to HTML divs, all nice, every post is different with its assigned postid (echoing the id returns correct id for each).

Where the problem starts is putting the postid of speciffic button clicked into javascript variable and into php script later on. I have posts with postids of "62, 61, 60, 59, etc" but getElementById("idOfClickedButton).textContent (right now i have it echoed in the button) only gets 62, no matter which one I'm clicking. Same thing with getElementById("idOfClickedButton).value, but this one gets the last loaded post (53 or 43 let's say) for every button.

I'd like to know how can I pass the assigned postid into a js variable.

```
//PHP variable of postid
$id=$row['p_id'];

//that's the paragraph that checks the postid
<p id="likeit" onclick="check()"><?php echo $id ?></p>

//JS script that checks the postid
<script>
function check(){
    var p = document.getElementById("likeit").textContent;
    console.log(p);
}
</script>
```

AJAX call works so I'm not including. Code above console logs "62" for every paragraph despite each having different textContent showing. [img of HTML of what it looks like and that it displays correct postid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evJRa.png) Highlighted is the paragraph used to check the id, button above is for an AJAX call.

Comment: Jamming the ID value into the content seems pretty messy. Why not a [`data` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)?

Comment: @tadman It's my first project that I'm using to learn everything in a real world scenario, not just Hello Worlds, so it doesn't have to fit the standard for production for me to just learn I guess

Comment: You're trying to learn, which is great, so why not learn the way that people usually do it? Half-measures are how you learn bad habits you need to later un-learn. It's not productive.

Comment: @tadman I get it, I'll try my best. Fortunately I'm learning out of curiosity, not with an intent of persuing it as a carreer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that would like to know my way around it:

```
//input inside a form
<input type="submit" onclick="check(this)" value="<?php echo $id ?>">

//AJAX call with value check

function check(el){

var pid = el.value;
console.log(pid);
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: { 
            liked: 1,
            pid: pid }
    });
    return false;
}); 
}
```

Although this solution stores already clicked values in a variable, effectively inputting +1 record with every click. Needs further tweeking

Answer (score 2):

```
<p id="likeit" onclick="check(this)"><?php echo $id ?></p>
```

Add this to the function

```
  function check(el){

        var p = document.getElementById("likeit").textContent;
        console.log(p);
        console.log(el.id);


    }
```

Comment: Tried this and "p" still logs as the same number (now 43 for whatever reason). Went as far as changing the element id to "likeit<?php echo $id ?>" to check if it's getting the element id right and it does log "likeit61, likeit52" etc, so I'm not sure anymore.
If element id logs correctly, can (and how?) I put it in the variable and then pass it into ajax?